# select user with least amount of tiquets between all other users

Tags: mysql, query, select, sqlite

I have a table where I store users info like this

| user | tickets |
| --- | --- |
| s.lewis | 0 |
| a.barrantes | 2 |
| x.mendez | 3 |
| j.robert | 0 |

I want to create a query to select the user that has the **least** amount of tickets between all other users. So in this table, it would return either *s.lewis* or *j.robert* (either one is ok)

Thanks so much :)

Comment: `.. ORDER BY tickets LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Akina's answer

```sql
select user, tickets from tablename
order by tickets limit 1
```

This selects both the user and the tickets for display.  The query orders it in ascending order and then limiting to 1 row (the first row).